# Django runs differently between python version?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku

Today I have come across wired error running the Django application with virtual environments.

The application runs without errors both locally and Heroku under python-3.5.1 with `Procfile`

`web: gunicorn --pythonpath='src/' proj.wsgi:application --log-file -`

And my project structure is:

```

```
.
├── LICENSE.txt
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── db.sqlite3
├── docs
├── env3
├── env
├── logs
├── manifest.yml
├── requirements
├── requirements.txt
├── run.sh
├── runtime.txt
├── site
└── src/proj
    ├── logger.py
    ├── settings
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── base.py
    │   ├── development.py
    │   └── production.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── views.py
    ├── wsgi.py
```

```

But when I run it with python 2.7.11 I get the following error

`ImportError: No module named proj.settings.development`

I could easily guess the error is related pythonpath config. However I am curious why in first place I am getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed now! The reason is that as the default django structure is rewritten every nested folder contains module need an `__init__.py`.

`src/proj` missing the `__init__.py`. Adding it fixed the error for python2. From `python3.3` this is not an requirement

Reference [PEP420](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-420-implicit-namespace-packages) https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/